# how to get USB guitar interface data with (preferably) python

Tags: python, audio, usb, guitar

I am wondering if anyone out there knows how I might go about getting audio data with a programming language from an M-Audio USB guitar interface? I would prefer to use python. I would like to get into live audio processing programming and am just curious where to start.

If anyone knows or has experience in getting data like this, even if it's not python, I would really appreciate a push in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for any links to python live music processing or audio libraries that might help.

Comment: The platform is also important.

Comment: @arunkumar, why in the world would you want to talk to USB directly?  That link you posted is completely inappropriate for this need.

Comment: Electric guitar with USB interface to plug in to my computer. I would like to do audio processing in real time for music that I am playing. I have access to Mac Linux and windows so whichever platform works easiest is what I prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can record from the device by using common audio recorder, such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), then you can use pyaudio.

[pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) is a python library binds for PortAudio. If you use C, you can use PortAudio directly.

Comment: Using pyAudio I was able to get input from the interface. This is the first step - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For Python, I might recommend [SndObj](http://sndobj.sourceforge.net/).  I haven't used it myself, but it seems to allow you to use ASIO, which is extremely important if you want low-latency audio IO.

Comment: Brad this looks very promising. I am still unsure of how to go about working with live audio input but I will give this a try tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Please post feedback here if you make progress!

Comment: Not a date to be found anywhere on the site... except the SourceForge download page, which says the latest release is from 2009. Is this actively developed? Is it good?